# How to get the DDLlist Selected Value in MVC C# Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, ddl, selected

**My coding are as following.**

I cannot get the selected value of AreaDetails_code dropdownlist selected value.

I got the null value only. Pls help me. Thanks in advance.

**In my Create.cshtml**

```
<div id="hsp-planner"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#butGenerate').click(`function generateTimeLine() {
                    $('#hsp-planner').html('');

                    var _location = $('#pAreaInfoId').val();
                    var _staff = $('#pStaff').val();

                    var _selVal = $('#AreaDetails_code').val();



                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxPlanner", "HourlyShiftPlanner")',

                        data: { location: _location, staff: _staff, selectval: _selVal },
                        //dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#hsp-planner').html(data);

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                });

    });
`

</script>
```

**In my Controller.cs**

```
public string GetAjaxPlanner()

{

string locationId = Request.QueryString["location"];
            string staffId = Request.QueryString["staff"];

            string selectVal = Request.QueryString["selectval"];

            //String str = (String)req.getParameter("AreaDetails_code");


            if (locationId != null && locationId != "")
            {
                List<ShiftAllocation> saList = new ShiftAllocationRepository().FindByAreaInfoId(int.Parse(locationId));


                if (saList.Count > 0)
                {
                    string result = "";

                    result = "<table>";

                    result += "<tr>";
                    result += "<td>Time Period<br/>(From-To)</td>";
                    result += "<td>Duty Location</td>";
                    //result += "<td>Remark</td>";
                    result += "<td>Staff</td>";
                    result += "</tr>";

                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (ShiftAllocation sa in saList)
                    {
                        HourlyShiftPlanner objHsp = null;

                        string dutyLocation = "";
                        string remark = "";

                        if (staffId != null && staffId != "")
                        {
                            objHsp = new HourlyShiftPlannerRepository().FindStaff(int.Parse(staffId), int.Parse(locationId), sa.ShiftAllocationId);
                        }

                        if (objHsp != null)
                        {
                            dutyLocation = objHsp.DutyLocation;
                            remark = objHsp.Remark;
                        }

                        result += "<tr>";
                        result += "<td>" + sa.FromShift.ToString("HH:mm") + "-" + sa.ToShift.ToString("HH:mm") + "</td>";
                        result += "<td>" + this.GetLocDetailsListWithDDL(i) + "</td>";


                        result += "</tr>";
                        result += "<input type='hidden' name='hidSAId" + i + "'  id='hid-sa-id" + i + "' value='" + sa.ShiftAllocationId + "'/>";

                        i++;
                    }

                    result += "</table>";

                    return result;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }




private string GetLocDetailsListWithDDL(int idx2)
        {
            List<AreaInfoDetails> _areaDetailsList = db.AreaInfosDetails.ToList();

            if (_areaDetailsList.Count == 0) return "";

            string result = "";

            result = "<select name='AreaDetails_code" + idx2 + "' id='AreaDetails_code" + idx2 + "'>";

            result += "<option value=>--Select item--</option>";

            foreach (AreaInfoDetails _ad in _areaDetailsList)
            {

                result += "<option value='" + _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId + "'>" + _ad.AreaDetailsCode + " </>";
            }

            result += "</select>";

            //result += "<input type=submit id=submit value=Submit  </>";

            return result;
        }`
```

Comment: use stringbuilder class to generate html tags with TagBuilder

Comment: How to do it ? pls write for me. Thanks

Comment: try it :
 result += "<option name='"+ _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId +"' value='" + _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId + "'>" + _ad.AreaDetailsCode + " </>";

Comment: result += "<option name='"+ _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId +"' value='" + _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId + "'>" + _ad.AreaDetailsCode + " </>";

i changed as per your suggestion. not work.

Comment: so, is the problem in this line: `var _selVal = $('#AreaDetails_code').val();`, you get _selVal always null? please confirm

Comment: yes always null. I think $('#AreaDetails_code').val() inside nothing.
But i never put get set for this. need to write ?

Comment: no need. Have you tried checking your generated ddl html in browser, is anything strange there? And also try $('#AreaDetails_code').val() in browser

Comment: How to do ? to check generated ddl html

Comment: I got

<select name='AreaDetails_code1' id='AreaDetails_code1'><option value=>--Select item--</option>
<option name='1' value='1'>GH </>
<option name='2' value='2'>ME1 </>
<option name='3' value='3'>SG1 </>
<option name='4' value='4'>CH </>
<option name='1002' value='1002'>SG2 </>
</select>"

Comment: I think this line: `result += "<option value='" + _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId + "'>" + _ad.AreaDetailsCode + " </>";` should be `result += "<option value='" + _ad.AreaInfoDetailsId + "'>" + _ad.AreaDetailsCode + " </option>";` let me know if that works..

Comment: Changed ready. Nothing. still NULL

Comment: another thing, change `result += "<option value=>--Select item--</option>";` to `result += "<option value=''>--Select item--</option>";`

Comment: changed ready. still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have this line:

```
result = "<select name='AreaDetails_code" + idx2 + "' id='AreaDetails_code" + idx2 + "'>";
```

where `idx2` is a variable int, when you're trying to obtain the value with jquery:

```
var _selVal = $('#AreaDetails_code').val();
```

you are not appending this `idx2` value in the selector and thus jquery assigns the value of null because it can't find it.

If you delete this placeholder from your controller, then you'll end up with multiple elements with the same id...no bueno. You must find a better naming convention or somehow pass that value to your view/javascript so it can know which element to get the value of.

Hope that helps.